# On HP Mini, unable to select 800x600 resolution

Tags: windows-xp, video, display-settings

I have an HP Mini laptop. I can only make resolution setting for my display of 1024x576. The HP Deskjet 6988 driver only allows resolution settings of 800x600. I don't care how 800x600 would look on my laptop, I only want to install the driver for the printer and set it back. I went into the registry, but it was showing a resolution setting of 800x600.

How else can I set the resolution or at least add the option in my Display Properties for 800x600?

Comment: Just in case all else fails: maybe you can use an external monitor? Or if you don't have one: use Windows Remote Assistance (or [things like TeamViewer](http://superuser.com/questions/1585/whats-the-best-remote-desktop-application)) and then connect to your laptop from another computer with a larger screen?

Comment: @Arjan: Thanks but no external monitor unfortunately. Remote Assistance is not possible either

Comment: My comment was really just meant as a last resort. But your reply makes me wonder why remote assistance would not be possible then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no solution to this problem until HP fixes their drivers.

Comment: Don't HP Mini's only have a 1024x576 screen - if so doesn't Windows limit you to what resolutions the screen supports?

Comment: @Blackbeagle: I don't know. But it does not let you set the resolution to allow the program to run.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the printer via the USB port on the HP Mini laptop then give HP's basic driver for your printer a try.  It may be all you need to do is download the basic driver then point Windows to it when it searches for a driver for your printer.  This way you can avoid the hassle of HP's install environment.  The [basic driver is available from HP](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareDownloadIndex?softwareitem=bi-39216-2&lc=en&dlc=en&cc=us&os=228&product=3422866&sw_lang=), assuming you are using Windows XP.

Comment: Unfortunately the basic driver has the same checks for an 800x600 resolution.